# Names and autocomplete from a third-party SDK are gone

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, sdk, decentraland

Previously working SDK environment stops recognize the names and provide autocomplete.
I want to know, what caused the problem and does it connected to SDK maintenance or maybe it goes offline?

This is a Decentraland SDK: 
https://docs.decentraland.org/getting-started/installation-guide/

Already reinstalled CLI, Node.js, Git bash and Visual Code.

The projects are building from command line as previously fine, but Visual Code stops to recognize SDK is installed and unrecognized specific names, instead marks them as an errors. Not a big deal, but I've lost autocomplete and receive warnings.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example project where you have this issue? You can for example use https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-ts for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred when opening a projects folder which does't contain 'node_modules' sub-folder. 
Include that dir on your opened folder or even sub-folder, to prevent above problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get node_modules installed in a scene directory:
1. Open the cmd prompt or terminal
2. Use cd to navigate to the scene directory
3. Run:.  npm i decentraland-ecs
4. Close and reopen Visual Studio Code